# Obtaining Comprehensive list of Android Devices support of Texture Compression Formats

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, unreal-development-kit

I'm looking for a list of Android devices and their relative OpenGL Texture Compression formats supported by it's hardware.

There are mainly four textures compression types supported on Android:

- ETC1 (Ericcson texture compression). This format is supported by all Android phones. But, It doesn't support an alpha channel, so can only be used for opaque textures.
- PVRTC (PowerVR texture compression). Supported by devices with PowerVR GPUs (Nexus S, Kindle fire...).
- ATITC (ATI texture compression).Used in devices with Adreno GPU from Qualcomm (Nexus One...).
- S3TC (S3 texture compression). This texture compression is used in the NVIDIA chipset integrated devices (Motorola Xoom...)

I have logging built in the game engine I'm working with that will tell me what format to use when I run my app on a single device, but I would like to find a trustworthy resource to use as reference.

Has anyone ever seen anything like this online anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **no** such list (at least not trustworthy) because

- there are several Android devices released every day
- there are more texture compression formats than you mentioned in your list (ETC2/EAC, ASTC, LATC, ...)
- there are more 3D HW vendors than you mentioned in your list (ARM Mali, Intel HD Graphics, Vivante, ...)

You should never rely on relation between 3D HW vendor & particular texture compression support, instead of this 
you should check for supported texture compressions run-time (after OpenGL/ES initialization) by looking for extension sub string in string returned by `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)`,
e.g "GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc" for S3TC, "GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc" for PVRTC.

Comment: Instead of checking extensions, a more streamlined approach is to use `glGetIntegerv(GL_COMPRESSED_TEXTURE_FORMATS, ...)` to enumerate the supported formats.